# Clear Var or Callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Sorry, i am not sure if I am asking the question correctly. When a date is changed by a user the date count down changes on the page. If the date is changed more than once it flashes all date changes. I guess it is storing the previous information somewhere. I have tried clearing the vars.

```
var deal_yeax = '';
```

as I would do in php with no luck

```
$('#deal_end').focusout(function() {
var deal_end = $("#deal_end").val();
var array = deal_end .split('-');
var deal_montx = array[0];
var deal_dax = array[1];
var deal_yeax = array[2];

    deal_montx = deal_montx - 1;

    $(function(){
    ts = new Date(deal_yeax ,  deal_montx  ,  deal_dax  );
    $(".h").countdown({
    timestamp   : ts,
    callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
    message_days = (days);
    var message_hours = (hours);
    $(".message_hours").text(message_hours + " Hours");
    var message_minutes = (minutes);
    $(".message_minutes").text(message_minutes + " Minutes");
    var message_seconds = (seconds);
        // Creat the display
        if ( message_days < 1 && message_hours < 1 ) { $(".message_seconds").text(message_seconds  + " Seconds"); }
        else if ( message_days < 1 && message_hours > 1 ) {  }
        else if ( message_days == 1 ) { $(".message_days").text(message_days + " Day"); }
        else { $(".message_days").text(message_days + " Days"); }

        if ( message_days < 1 && message_hours < 1 && message_minutes < 1 && seconds < 1 ) {
        $(".hide_my_buy_button").fadeOut("fast"); 
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: `ts` and `message_days` are global variables. Add **`var`** before first usage of them.

Comment: @c69 thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @MHowey That's why he wrote it in a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you "focusout" from `#deal_end`, you'll attach a `countdown` event to `.h`. Without knowing exactly how `countdown(...)` works (It'll be good if you provide the source so we can provide more help!), one way to fix the issue maybe to use JQuery's `unbind(...)` function to remove existing listeners on an event before adding a new one to it.

Here's an example on the issue:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <input id="text" />
    <button id="clicker" />
</div>

<!-- Javascript -->
$('#text').focusout(function() {
    var text = this.value;

    // Everytime #text is "focused out", a new event is registered with #clicker.
    $('#clicker').click(function() {
        console.log('Value: ' + text);
    });
});
```

... and here's how to solve the issue (It's just one of the many ways. This way is probably not the most elegant but anyhow.)

```
$('#text').focusout(function() {
    var text = this.value;

    $('#clicker').unbind('click');
    // Everytime #text is "focused out", a new event is registered with #clicker.
    $('#clicker').click(function() {
        console.log('Value: ' + text);
    });
});
```

Bottom line: It seems focusout(...) is adding a new `countdown` everytime it is triggered. That might be the problem you're having.

Not sure if this helps?  Lemme know.

P.S. JSFiddle to go with it: http://jsfiddle.net/PE9eW/

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with .countdown function that you are using in your code to flash the date changes. When you assign a new count down object to $(".h") the plugin or the function probably assign some event handler or interval to it, but it doesn't seem to clear the old ones when it is called again and that is why it flashing all the dates for each countdown. So you will have to do it manually. I am not sure if you are using an external plugin or is it your own function but what you need to do is to clear the existing events or intervals that is assigned to your element when you call the function. I can be more helpful if you tell me which plugin you are using or maybe show the code if it is your own function. (referring to .countdown() )